# MongoDB read data from multi data centre with low latency

Tags: python, mongodb, sharding

MongoDB read data from multiple data centre, (I have setup mangodb replicated with two data centre). I want to do write on one data centre and am able to replicate data on data centre 1 to data centre 2.

Now my need is read the data from data centre 2 and write from data centre 1.

## Data centre 1:

Mongos ----> |config 1,config 2,config 3| --> mongodb(shard and replicated)

## Data centre 2:

mongodb(replicated and shard connected to data centre 1)

So through **mongos** i want to read data from data centre 1
or is there a best way to transport config db meta info to Data centre 2

Any Suggestions and code snippet are welcome to achieve this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question has several conflicts. You first state that you want to write from (to?) data centre 1 and read from data centre 2. Then you state at the end of your question you want to read from data centre 1. You need to clarify your question and which Mongo instances are acting as secondaries and primaries.

Comment: Data centre 1 has primary and secondary. And data centre 2 has secondary only(slave). Now am adding a json consider {"_id":1234,"ADV":1} am writing this to data centre 1. Now I want read this data from data centre 2 using "_id".

Answer (score 1):

You can read from secondaries using your driver's read preference by setting it to either, secondary, secondary preferred, or nearest. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/

Comment: Do you mean secondaries of Data center 2, If so do i need to enable Tag aware sharding or hash based sharding ??